# WCF - Error in response during a signed communication

Tags: c#, wcf, response, message, sign

I have a client that sign the body of a message.

The class structure is:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "simpleEncryptInput", WrapperNamespace = "http://xxx/2013/06/schemas/simple", IsWrapped = true,  ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
public partial class SimpleEncryptOperationRequest {

[System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/eip/2013/07/schemas/business",  ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None)]
    public TestFirmando2.ServiceReference1.BusinessHeader businessHeader;

[System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/eip/2013/08/schemas/technical",  ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None)]
    public TestFirmando2.ServiceReference1.TechnicalHeader technicalHeader;

[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://xxx/2013/06/schemas/simple", Order = 0,  ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
    public string @in;

    public SimpleEncryptOperationRequest() {
    }

    public SimpleEncryptOperationRequest(TestFirmando2.ServiceReference1.BusinessHeader businessHeader, TestFirmando2.ServiceReference1.TechnicalHeader technicalHeader, string @in) {
        this.businessHeader = businessHeader;
        this.technicalHeader = technicalHeader;
        this.@in = @in;
    }
}
```

In the app.config file I use a customBinding element as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="customSecurity">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" requireDerivedKeys="false" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="ClientEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" requireSecurityContextCancellation="false" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">     
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:5521/ws/SPAIF_Test1_POC_SOA_vs1" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="customSecurity" contract="ServiceReference1.SimpleService" name="SPAIF_Test1_POC_SOA_vs1soaphttp" behaviorConfiguration="AxaWCFBehaviourX509">
    <identity>
      <dns value="partner1" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AxaWCFBehaviourX509">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="partner1" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPublisher" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <defaultCertificate findValue="partner1" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPublisher" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

With this configuration, the body message is signed and the server process successfully. When the server respond and the WCF client proxy process the response a exception :

```
The businessHeader', 'http://xxx/eip/2013/07/schemas/business', required message part was not signed.
```

I see the response message and the body is signed but not that header, I’m not configured the application to sign this header and I cannot see anywhere where this header would be required.

Why the proxy throws the exception? Why does it say that the header has to be signed?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you change the message contract attribute so that it is not protected but leave the protection for the different elements will it work? My guess is the contract level is overriding the header.

Comment: Thanks Kevin but I have just changed the protection level in the class to None and deleting the whole ProtectionLevel attribute but in both cases I've gotten the same exception. :(

Comment: have you got a solution for your issue?